# Unable to consume all new Kinesis messages

Tags: java, amazon-kinesis

I'm converting a Java application from Kafka to Kinesis. This application runs forever. It sleeps for 30 seconds, then wakes up, runs some HBase queries, consumes and processes any new Kafka messages, then sleeps again.

This works fine in Kafka - that's exactly what the default Consumer does. However this is not the case in Kinesis. Consuming from the KCL requires the KCL consumer to be running at all times, which doesn't work for my needs. I need to be able to consume all new messages as required with a single method call.

The official documentation for the Kinesis Java API says:

> You retrieve records from the stream on a per-shard basis. For each shard, and for each batch of records that you retrieve from that shard, you need to obtain a shard iterator.

and

> If no records are returned, that means no data records are currently available from this shard at the sequence number referenced by the shard iterator. When this situation occurs, your application should wait for an amount of time

But I don't care about shards! I just want to get all messages since I last consumed, in one method call. And what if my app dies and needs to restart; how will it know where to resume?

Current code:

```
GetRecordsRequest getRecordsRequest = new GetRecordsRequest();
getRecordsRequest.setShardIterator(TRIM_HORIZON);
getRecordsRequest.setLimit(25); 

GetRecordsResult result = client.getRecords(getRecordsRequest);

// Put the result into record list. The result can be empty.
records = result.getRecords();
```

**EDIT**

To be clearer, with Kafka I can run:

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = this.consumer.poll(0);
```

to get all unconsumed messages. If my app dies and restarts, there's no problem, offsets are taken care of and I'll resume where I left off.

How do I do this in Kinesis?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can use with `StockTradeRecordProcessor` where it has the option to reset the stats which in turn enable to consume only the new messages. Refer [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-kinesis-learning/blob/master/src/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/samples/stocktrades/processor/StockTradeRecordProcessor.java) to find the implementation of `StockTradeRecordProcessor`.

But on a hard note,  `This method uses 60-second intervals for the reporting and checkpointing rate` but not 30 seconds as your application demands.

Comment: Thanks but this uses the KCL, so I can't call `processRecords(...)` whenever I want to read messages. I'd rather not have to re-build my app to exist within this one method as Kinesis is only a small part of it.